# How to initialize an array of pointers to string in the constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I want to use an array in this way:

```
class Foo {
    std::string *arrayOfPointersToString[]; // Array of pointers to string
    int N;
public:
    Foo(int capacity) : N(capacity) {
        arrayOfPointersToString = new std::string[capacity];
    }
};
```

But i have an error: Incompatible pointer types. What can i do?

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: `arrayOfPointersToString = new std::string*[capacity];`

Comment: it is part of the assignment...

Comment: An array of pointers to strings makes little sense. Perhaps your assignment could be satisfied with an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing too much about the reason why you want to dynamically allocate an array of strings, you would use this:

```
std::string *stringArray = new std::string[5];
```

But, if you want a dynamically allocated array of string pointers, a possible solution is to use this instead:

```
class foo{
    std::string ** arrayOfStringPointersToString;
public:
    foo(int capacity) : N(capacity) {
        arrayOfPointersToString = new std::string*[capacity];
    }
}
```

A key thing to note is that the values of each index is not guranteed to be null, so for each index you will need to either

1. call `new` on each of them and assign their values.
2. assign them to the address of another variable.

Also, since you will be managing the dynamic memory yourself, remember to call `delete` on everything you allocate with `new`, and make sure you call `delete[]` on everything you allocate with `new[]`.

Comment: A good resource for dynamic memory is:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Answer (score 1):

The incompatibility error is because you have declared the array to hold pointers, but are then trying to allocate an array of actual `std::string` objects instead of an array of pointers.

If you want an array of pointers, you need to fix your `new[]` statement to allocate an array of pointers instead of an array of objects:

```
class Foo {
    std::string* arrayOfPointersToStrings[];
    int N;
public:
    Foo(int capacity) : N(capacity) {
        arrayOfPointersToStrings = new std::string*[capacity];
    }
    ~Foo() {
        delete[] arrayOfPointersToStrings;
    }
};
```

But, if you want an array of objects, you need to fix your array declaration to declare an array of objects instead of an array of pointers:

```
class Foo {
    std::string* arrayOfStrings;
    int N;
public:
    Foo(int capacity) : N(capacity) {
        arrayOfStrings = new std::string[capacity];
    }
    ~Foo() {
        delete[] arrayOfStrings;
    }
};
```

Either way, you should use `std::vector` instead of using `new[]`/`delete[]` manually:

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<std::string*> arrayOfPointersToStrings;
public:
    Foo(int capacity) : arrayOfPointersToStrings(capacity) {}
};
```

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<std::string> arrayOfStrings;
public:
    Foo(int capacity) : arrayOfStrings(capacity) {}
};
```